# Is it possible to achieve negative X-Skewing without cropping in Python PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, transformation, skew

Im working on to transform images using X-skew using the following code

```py
from PIL import Image

def x_skew_image(input_path, output_path, skew_factor):
    # Open the input image
    input_image = Image.open(input_path)

    # Get the image dimensions
    width, height = input_image.size

    # Calculate the new width after skewing
    new_width = int(width + abs(skew_factor) * height)

    # Create a new image with the calculated width and the same height
    output_image = Image.new("RGB", (new_width, height))

    # Apply the skew transformation
    for y in range(height):
        x_offset = int(skew_factor * y)
        for x in range(width):
            if 0 <= x + x_offset < new_width:
                output_image.putpixel((x + x_offset, y), input_image.getpixel((x, y)))

    # Save the skewed image
    output_image.save(output_path)

# Replace these paths and skew_factor as needed
input_path = r'input_path'  # Replace with the path to your input image
output_path = r'output_path'  # Replace with the desired output path
skew_factor = -0.4  # Adjust the skew factor as needed

x_skew_image(input_path, output_path, skew_factor)
```

However, Im facing issue when trying to with negative X-skewing (change **skew_factor** to negative value) and it seems that the image get cropped. How can i modify the code to solve the issue?

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ksXa.jpg)

[Positive X-skew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6wuK.jpg)

[Negative X-skew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAawD.jpg)

Comment: file a bug report with the PIL project.

Comment: I added some new examples for a) a solid background and b) a background with a blurred version of your original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works if you change it to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

def x_skew_image(input_path, output_path, skew_factor):
    # Open the input image
    input_image = Image.open(input_path)

    # Get the image dimensions
    width, height = input_image.size

    # Calculate the new width after skewing
    new_width = int(width + abs(skew_factor) * height)

    # Create a new image with the calculated width and the same height
    output_image = Image.new("RGB", (new_width, height))

    # Apply the skew transformation
    for y in range(height):
        x_offset = int(skew_factor * y)
        if skew_factor < 0:
            x_offset = int(-skew_factor * (height - y))
            
        for x in range(width):
            new_x = x + x_offset
            output_image.putpixel((new_x, y), input_image.getpixel((x, y)))

    # Save the skewed image
    output_image.save(output_path)

# Replace these paths and skew_factor as needed
input_path = 'CrazyCat.jpg'
output_path = 'result.jpg'
skew_factor = -0.4  # Adjust the skew factor as needed

x_skew_image(input_path, output_path, skew_factor)
```

[image]

With `skew_factor=0.4`:

[image]

With `skew_factor=-0.4`:

[image]

---

However, I would really advise **AGAINST** using `for` loops for image processing in Python - they are slow and error-prone. There is a noticeable delay when running your code versus using the built-in affine transform method which is instantaneous and simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

input_path  = 'CrazyCat.jpg'
output_path = 'result.jpg'

im = Image.open(input_path)
w , h = im.size

shear_factor = 0.4
new_width = int(w + abs(shear_factor)*h)
if shear_factor > 0:
   res = im.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, -shear_factor*h, 0, 1, 0))
else:
   res = im.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, 0, 0, 1, 0))

res.save('result.jpg')
```

---

Referring to your secondary question about filling the surrounding black area, you can try this for a solid greenish colour:

```
res = im.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, -shear_factor*h, 0, 1, 0), fillcolor='#506050')
```

[image]

---

If you want to fill the undefined parts of your sheared image with a blurred version of your original image, you can do that like this - your tastes on blur radius and so on may vary but you should get the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

input_path = 'CrazyCat.jpg'
output_path = 'result.jpg'

# Open image and get dimensions
im = Image.open(input_path)
w , h = im.size

# Generate same-size mask for choosing where to paste sheared image onto blurred background
mask = Image.new('L', (w,h), 'white')
mask.save('DEBUG-mask.jpg') # debug only

# Shear using affine transform
shear_factor = 0.4
new_width = int(w + abs(shear_factor)*h)
if shear_factor > 0:
   res  = im.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, -shear_factor*h, 0, 1, 0))
   mask = mask.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, -shear_factor*h, 0, 1, 0))
else:
   res  = im.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, 0, 0, 1, 0))
   mask = mask.transform((new_width,h), Image.AFFINE, (1, shear_factor, 0, 0, 1, 0))

# Generate blurred, extended backgound
bg = im.copy().resize((new_width,h)).filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(50))
bg.save('DEBUG-bg.jpg') # debug only

# Paste sheared original over blurred background using mask to select which image to source from
bg.paste(res, mask)
bg.save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Is the the black part of the skewed image can be fill with background of the original image?

Comment: It depends what you mean by *"background"*. If you mean one, single, solid colour such as light-green, you can add a `fillcolor` parameter to `transform()`, see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transform If you mean a blurred version of the original including tonal variation, you would need to stretch the original to the same size as the skewed version and blur it. Then you'd take a solid white image, same size as original and skew it same way. Then use `paste()` with the bkack&white image as the `mask` parameter to `paste()`.

Comment: What if my image is like this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukemia). Can i have that non-solid background color based on the original image to fill the black part of skewed image?

Comment: I tried that image and it works fine too. You may want to use a smaller blur factor of say 10, instead of 50 (4 lines from the bottom) because that image is smaller than the crazy cat.